# Anthos "Unreachable Agent - please check if GKE Connect Agent is deployed correctly."

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I have successfully created an Anthos cluster with a simple command from the [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/multi-cloud/aws/how-to/create-cluster).

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error in GCP Console:

> Unreachable Agent - please check if GKE Connect Agent is deployed correctly.

On the other side, the control plane on AWS is healthy with running kubelets, kube-api-servers, gke_multicloud_agent, and other Kubernetes-related processes.

---

Also, I've authorized Cloud Logging for this cluster, but getting only 2 types of errors. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure those two are not related to the GKE Connect Agent errors:

> unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request

&

> loading OpenAPI spec for "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" failed with: failed to retrieve openAPI spec, http error: ResponseCode: 503, Body: service unavailable

---

Does anyone know how should I debug issues with GKE Connect Agent connectivity?

Comment: Besides the document [Create a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/multi-cloud/aws/how-to/create-cluster), can you review and follow the steps described in [Prerequisites for registering a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/prerequisites#set_up_identity)? Specifically the section [Set up an identity for use by the Connect Agent](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/prerequisites#set_up_an_identity_for_use_by_the).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by following the official terraform [anthos-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/anthos-samples/tree/main/anthos-multi-cloud/AWS).

It seems the Connect Agent pod will be installed on one of the nodes from the node-pool once it's created.

The [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/multi-cloud/aws/how-to/create-cluster) is a bit misleading because it's not mentioning Connect Agent won't exist with only control-plane up and running.